# Shiny server - This package is uninstallable?

Tags: r, shiny-server

I use the command lines below to install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-base

$ sudo su - \
-c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""

$ sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
$ wget https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.4.1.759-amd64.deb
$ sudo gdebi shiny-server-1.4.1.759-amd64.deb
```

Error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libssl0.9.8
```

Any ideas why?

I followed those command lines from the shiny [website](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#ubuntu-12.04) itself sometime ago. Now it has changed and failed to install with the current instructions. I have followed this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) too but no luck at all.

Any ideas?

I'm on ubuntu **16.04** now btw.

Answer (score 5):

Use the last version of rstudio which use the last version lo libssl, which probably is installed in your system:
For that execute below commands:

- 64bit

  `$ sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
  $ wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-1.1.383-amd64.deb
  $ sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.1.383-amd64.deb`
- 32bit

  `$ sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
  $ wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-1.1.383-i386.deb
  $ sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.1.383-i386.deb`


  For more info go to: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem but was able to get around it by installing the most recent version of shiny server.

You can check to see if libssl0.9.8 is even installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep ssl
```

Likely it is not (perhaps it is deprecated).

In the [tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-rstudio-shiny-server-on-aws/), it recommends you use the [latest version](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/) of shiny-server. See if you can successfully install a more recent version.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
$ wget https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-<latest-version>-amd64.deb
$ sudo gdebi shiny-server-<latest-version>-amd64.deb
```